# Android 11, packageManager.resolveActivity() returns null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-11

It is using `packageManager.resolveActivity` to check the activity when receiving FCM notification and preparing the `Intent` (so there is no `startActivity()` call directly).

It works on other os version but not on android 11, the `packageManager.resolveActivity` returns null:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.yahoo.com"));
 ResolveInfo info = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

following the https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#open-urls-browser-or-other-app,

added in manifest:

```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <!-- <data android:scheme="*" /> --> //<== with or without this line it is the same
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

However, it still returns null.

Any suggestion/solution?

Comment: What happens if you use `<data android:scheme="https" />`?

Comment: @CommonsWare, did use the "https" for scheme at first it did not work either.

Comment: The example `<queries>` section in Android docs is slightly different, it has a `category` element, have you tried adding it? https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#open-urls